# Disabling view state and event validation through Web.config Not Working

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I have to disable view state and event validation through Web.config on IIS 7 hosted website but isn't working.Same is working fine in debug mode or if i disable at page level then also working on hosted site.

Settings in web.config:

```
< pages buffer="true" validateRequest="true" enableViewState="false" enableEventValidation="false">
</pages>
```